# Opcode for moving quadword to %RDI

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

Let's say I have a `malloc`-ed variable and I want to move it's address to `%rdi`, all that generating the opcode from C. It should look to something like this:

```
unsigned char op_1[] = { 0x48, 0x8B, 0x3C, 0x25 }; //movq
unsigned char *a = malloc(1); // Let's asume a is now at 0x1234567812345678
unsigned char *bytecode = malloc(sizeof(op_1) + sizeof(void *)); // 12 bytes
memcpy(bytecode, op_1, sizeof(op_1)); // 4 bytes
memcpy(bytecode + sizeof(op_1), &a, sizeof(void *)); // 8 bytes
```

That should leave the content of `bytecode` to: `48 8B 3C 25 78 56 34 12 78 56 34 12`.
Anyways, that is invalid bytecode, as (if I'm not misreading the docs) `48 8B 3C 25` can be followed by 4 bytes for the address.

My question is how am I supposed to move an 8 bytes long address to `%rdi`?

Comment: You cannot "malloc a variable". You "malloc memory", and store the pointer to that memory in a variable.

Comment: @KerrekSB True, I just expressed myself wrong

Comment: You should somewhere identify the CPU you are working with. It is crucial information. In some circumstances (but not this question), you might also need to identify the assembler language for that CPU; there are different conventions for different x86 assemblers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the right opcode is `48 bf`. I compile the following assembly (using Intel syntax and `nasm`):

```
BITS 64
        mov rdi, 0x1234567812345678
```

Then I pass the result through `objdump -d -w -Mintel`:

```
0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   48 bf 78 56 34 12 78 56 34 12   movabs rdi,0x1234567812345678
```

The opcode `48 bf` is composed of the REX.W prefix `48` to designate 64-bit operands, the opcode `b8 +`*`rd io`*, and the register selector for `RDI` (`111`):

> `MOV r64, imm64`: Move `imm64` to `r64`

Comment: Hmmm, let me try, please.

Comment: Weird. Why would ```echo "movq 2, %rdi" | as -o /dev/null -64 -al -msyntax=att -mnaked-reg``` return ```48 8B``` instead of ```48 BF``` (as in ```movq``` instead of ```mov```)? That behavior (bug?) confused me.

Comment: @alexandernst: Are you misunderstanding the syntax? Immediate values in AT&T syntax are prefixed with `$`. With the corrected version, I get `48C7C702`, which is "move imm32 with sign extension" (because of the small operand).

Comment: @alexandernst: The meta moral is to stop using the ridiculous AT&T syntax, which has no redeeming qualities.

Comment: ```movq 2, %rdi``` is (iirc) valid AT&T syntax when used with ```as```.  That said, should I switch to Intel syntax? Will it bring me any benefits? (I'm already kind of used to AT&T). Anyways. my point is that I think ```as``` is acting in a strange way. Take a look at this for example: ```movq 0x1234567812345678, %rdi``` will return ```Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'```, but ```movq 0x12345678, %rdi``` will return ```488B3C2578563412```. Why is that?

Comment: @alexandernst: No idea. Intel syntax is just so much less noisy. All the instruction and operand sizes are simply deduced whenever possible, so there's just a single `mov` mnemonic. That way it matches the description in the Intel manual...

Comment: It looks like ```as``` is playing nicer with Intel syntax, so I'll be using that one instead :) . Also, the main problem is fixed, thank you very much!

Comment: I think there's a typo: and the opcode b8 +rd io -> and the opcode bf +rd io ???  Else, how does bf become b8?

Comment: @NickDesaulniers: The opcode is packed into the first 5 bits of the operand, the last 3 bits select the register (`111` selects RDI).